# Unable to publish Pubsub message in Airflow Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-composer

I am unable to publish using the `PubSubHook` in Airflow with Python 3. Everything works perfectly with Python 2, but with Python 3 I get this error `{models.py:1760} ERROR - Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable`. It seems that encoding the message in Python 3 results in a byte that then can't be handled by the JSON serializer.

The following works fine in Python 2:

```
def send_message_to_pubsub(message):
    pubsub_message = {'data': b64encode(message)}
    hook = PubSubHook(gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default')
    hook.publish('project-name', 'topic-name', [pubsub_message])
```

The example [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/example_dags/example_pubsub_flow.py) doesn't work as well with Python 3.

**Update 1:**

Tried with the following but got error:

```
def send_message_to_pubsub():
    message = 'Test message'
    pubsub_message = {'data': b64encode(message).decode()}
    hook = PubSubHook(gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default')
    hook.publish('project-name', 'topic-name', [pubsub_message])

{base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1962: Subtask pub_sub_test [2019-03-18 17:10:28,903] {models.py:1760} ERROR - a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
{base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1962: Subtask pub_sub_test Traceback (most recent call last):
{base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1962: Subtask pub_sub_test   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1659, in _run_raw_task
{base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1962: Subtask pub_sub_test     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
{base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1962: Subtask pub_sub_test   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 95, in execute
{base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1962: Subtask pub_sub_test     return_value = self.execute_callable()
{base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1962: Subtask pub_sub_test   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 100, in execute_callable
{base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1962: Subtask pub_sub_test     return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
{base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1962: Subtask pub_sub_test   File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/pubsub-test-dag.py", line 31, in send_message_to_pubsub
{base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1962: Subtask pub_sub_test     pubsub_message = {'data': b64encode(message).decode()}
{base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1962: Subtask pub_sub_test   File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
{base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1962: Subtask pub_sub_test     encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
{base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 1962: Subtask pub_sub_test TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

**Update 2:**

Tried with the following, resulted in a different error. This time from JSON serializer:

```
def send_message_to_pubsub():
    message = 'Test message'
    pubsub_message = {'data': b64encode(message.encode())}
    hook = PubSubHook(gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default')
    hook.publish('project', 'topic', [pubsub_message]) 

[2019-03-19 10:44:29,845] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test [2019-03-19 10:44:29,841] {models.py:1760} ERROR - Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,846] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test Traceback (most recent call last):
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,846] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models.py", line 1659, in _run_raw_task
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,847] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test     result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,847] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 95, in execute
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,847] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test     return_value = self.execute_callable()
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,847] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 100, in execute_callable
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,848] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test     return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,848] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test   File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/pubsub-test-dag.py", line 33, in send_message_to_pubsub
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,848] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test     hook.publish('project', 'topic', [pubsub_message])
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,848] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test   File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_pubsub_hook.py", line 75, in publish
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,849] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test     topic=full_topic, body=body)
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,849] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test   File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 795, in method
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,849] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test     actual_path_params, actual_query_params, body_value)
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,850] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test   File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/model.py", line 151, in request
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,850] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test     body_value = self.serialize(body_value)
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,850] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test   File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/model.py", line 260, in serialize
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,850] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test     return json.dumps(body_value)
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,851] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test   File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,851] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test     return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,853] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test   File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,853] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test     chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,853] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test   File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,854] {base_task_runner.py:101} INFO - Job 2172: Subtask pub_sub_test     return _iterencode(o, 0)
[2019-03-19 10:44:29,852] {models.py:1791} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
```

Comment: Which line of code from your code snippet thrown that error message?

Comment: It errors out in the models.py as stated above. It seems that the cause of the error is the way strings are stored in Python 2 vs Python 3. Airflow seems to be serializing the request (to the REST endpoint of PubSub) using JSON serializer somewhere in the models.py. However, JSON serializer only works with string data and encoding the data in Python 3, as above, creates a byte version of the message.

Comment: which version of Airflow are you using?

Comment: Airflow version 1.10.1 via GCP Cloud Composer, Python version 3.6

Comment: The result of `b64encode(message)` is bytes for Python 3. Change it to `b64encode(message).decode()`.

Comment: Just tried, it errors out. Please see Update 1 for error details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This questions has two sides.

1. Per the [base64 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode), your message must be of type `bytes` rather than `str`. To verify this, try `assert isinstance(message, bytes)`. This'll error out.

The solution depends on where your message is coming from.

- If your message is a string, you should encode it into bytes before sending down to base64:

```py
b64encode(message.encode())
```

- If your message is supposed to be of type `bytes`, you should change how you're reading it into Python.

---

2. Per the [JSON module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage) in Python, `byte` types are hnot supported. They must be `str` types. This means that whatever you send into the PubSub API must be as a string. So you can decode that into a string like so:

```py
pubsub_message = {'data': b64encode(message.encode()).decode()}
```

Comment: The message is plain text as per the code excerpt in Update 1. Tried `b64encode(message.encode())` but got a different error this time. Please see **Update 2**

Comment: Have you tried both solutions? `pubsub_message = {'data': b64encode(message.encode()).decode()}`

Comment: Should have tried as per your second suggestion. It works with `pubsub_message = {'data': b64encode(message.encode()).decode()}`. Thanks a lot for your help!!!